# At what level is OGRSpatialReference defined for vector datasets?

Tags: shapefile, gdal

I'm creating a c++ library that needs to communicate with the gdal/ogr world through its c++/c API. I'm relying on gdal 2.0+, and while I like the integration between the raster and vector portions of the library, there are a few points on which I'm confused. One of these points concerns how OGRSpatialReference instances are associated with GDALDatasets, GDALRasterBands, OGRLayers and the like. From the documentation, it seems clear that on the raster side, the OGRSpatialReference is directly associated with the GDALDataset and all GDALRasterBands belonging to a dataset are required to share the owning dataset's OGRSpatialReference. It is less clear that this is the case on the vector side. It's also unclear to me what the relationship is between a projection reference and a spatial reference in the context of the gdal API. So my questions are:

- Does `GDALDataset::GetProjectionRef()` give the WKT string necessary to construct an OGRSpatialReference for non-projected geographic reference systems? I presume it does, but would like to confirm.
- Are all OGRLayers belonging to a single GDALDataset required to share the same spatial reference?
- Can I always get the OGRSpatialReference for an OGRLayer from the owning GDALDataset with `GDALDataset::GetProjectionRef()`, or is it possible that I'll encounter datasets for which I'll need to get a layer's spatial reference directly from the layer with `OGRLayer::GetSpatialRef()`?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.